# Parse json from php in js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have array in my php file:

```
    $invoices_arr = [];

    foreach ($invoices as $key=>$invoice){
    $invoices_arr[$key]['id']=$invoice->get_id();
    $invoices_arr[$key]['code_text']=$invoice->get_code_text();
    $invoices_arr[$key]['invoice_name']=$invoice->get_invoice_name();
    $invoices_arr[$key]['status_invoice']=$invoice->get_status_invoice();
    $invoices_arr[$key]['attachments']=$invoice->get_attachments();
}
echo json_encode(['invoices'=>$invoices_arr]);
```

My ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                data:{lead_id:$("#lead_id").val()},
                url: sJSUrlGetAllLeadInvoices,
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#all_invoice_table tbody").empty();


                    $(obj.invoices).each(function(key,value){
                        $('#all_invoice_table').append('<tr><td>'+value.invoice_name+'</td><td class="invoice_status">'+value.status_invoice+'<td>attt</td><td><button id="'+value.id+'" class="edit_invoice_'+value.id+'">Edit invoice</button</td><td><button class="send_invoice_btn_'+value.id+'">Send invoice</button></td><td><img class="delete_invoice_'+value.id+'" src="/images/icons/delete.gif"></td><td class="invoice_hidden_column_'+value.id+'">'+value.code_text+'</td></tr>');
 });
   }
    });
```

In field `value.attachments` there is php serialize array, for example, string "a:1:{i:0;s:36:"../../pdf_invoices/2017-10-10015.pdf";}" . 
How can I convert this string to array in js?

I try do it:

```
       var mas=JSON.parse(value.attachments);
```

But I get error **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

How can I solve it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Best way is convert this string to array in PHP. `unserialize($invoice->get_attachments())`

Comment: Yes, unserialize helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should unserialize inside PHP code before encode in json

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the result with jQuery.parseJSON because jQuery do it for. If you inspect data using console.log() you will see that is a Javascript object ready for to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass datatype as json.
you can use jQuery parse method for parsing json response.

> datatype:json